# What do I do after successfully running my Android application on an emulator?

Tags: java, android, netbeans

My emulator finally displayed what I was asking for, now how do I put it in my Android device? I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#move)** command line tool

1 -- Get the list of devices using the **adb devices** command

> ```
> > adb devices
> emulator-5556
> ```

2 -- Install using **adb install**

```
  > adb install <path_to_apk>
  e.g.

  > adb -s emulator-5556 install helloWorld.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about netbeans as I use eclipse, but try connecting the device and installing all the driver necessary. Then try launching the project, it will probably give you a choice between the emulator and the device. Select the device, and wait for a while before the app loads.

Comment: how do i install the drivers of the device? i'm actually not used to android because i have an iphone. but we were instructed to make an android app...

Comment: I have samsung so I downloaded Kies to install the drivers for me. What phone are you using?

Comment: sorry, it's my brother's old phone so i don't. but i'm installing it now. what to do after that?

Comment: In your phone, goto settings->development->usb debugging. Turn it on. Install Kies, wait for the drivers to install. It'd be better if you had eclipse, but if you dont try launching your activity. Hopefully it will give you an option to choose between the device or the emulator.

Comment: actually, netbeans let me choose whether to run it on a device or a AVD. i chose AVD because i was still having problems with my device because it's wasn't being recognized by netbeans. i hope it works out later...